# How can I get the current context of webapplication without HttpRequest?

Tags: java, jsp, contextpath

I have a question because of the context of my application.

I work currently on a project and I need the current context URL from my web application to call another application? If possible without HTTP Request.
I need this because I use different Tomcats and environments for this application.
I don't like hard coding paths in properties or java code.

Comment: Hard-coding *what*? `HttpServletRequest` is a part of the portable Servlet API for a reason.

Comment: Where and what are doing hard coding? can you explain a bit more with some example?

Comment: You mean how to get the context of an application on a different server rather than hardcoding the URL of the application on the second server in the first one?

Comment: The problem is just not that always runs the application on the same server. At the same time, the second server changes. So far, it has a hard-coded with absolute path works, but I want to change that. It should always automatically detect on which server it runs and just hang the context.

Answer (score 1):

How about a sendRedirect in the HTTPServletResponse? Once you're done with your first request, your servlet is going to tell the client to go and call your "other application".

Comment: Hi ra2085. Thanks you're right. I get thi Context and save it in a static variable or systemproperty, so i can get it from the java class where i need it easier.

Answer (score 0):

It's since Servlet 2.5 (e.g. Tomcat 6 and newer) also available by [`ServletContext#getContextPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContextPath()).